# fopen seg. fault. Filename: 10000000 Size: 47M

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, fopen

first thanks for reading the question.

I have a weird seg. fault while trying to open a file, the code is simple:

```
f = fopen(itoa(SZ,10),"r");
```

SZ is a variable I set at compiling time to select which file I'm opening (is a programm to optimize an algorism and I'm trying it with different size problems). Debugging with gdb shows that itoa seems to be working ok.

I have no problem with the other files (ls output) :

```
489  Jan  4 19:34 100
4.8K Jan  4 19:34 1000
48K  Jan  4 19:34 10000
478K Jan  4 19:34 100000
4.7M Jan  4 19:34 1000000
47M  Jan  4 19:34 10000000
```

any idea?

thanks

P.D: itoa code:

```
char *itoa(int val, int base) {

    static char buf[32] = {0};
    int i = 30;
    for(; val && i ; --i, val /= base)
        buf[i] = "0123456789abcdef"[val % base];
    return &buf[i+1];
}
```

Comment: Don't know about the seg fault, but don't try to use that `itoa()` function with anything less than or equal to `0`.

Comment: Is the seg fault actually during the `fopen()` call? Do either of these seg fault?: `f = fopen("10000000","r");`, `f = fopen(itoa(10000000,10),"r");`

Comment: Oops ... - what platform is this running on?

Comment: Linux 3.0.6-gentoo x86_64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU 930 @ 2.80GHz

Answer (score 0):

Since you commented that `fopen("10000000","r");` fails as well, I'm going to go out on a limb and say that `fopen()` is failing and returning a `NULL` `FILE*`.  When you subsequently use that file pointer, you get a seg fault.

`fopen()` might be failing because of a permissions problem maybe - I don't know.

Check whether or not `fopen()` succeeds, and if it fails dump `errno`.

Comment: No, fopen doesn't succeeds. But I discovered something: The segmentation fault is always at the fopen. But if I try 

    fopen("10000000","r"); 
compiling with SZ=10000000 it  crashes. But if I compile it with SZ=1000000 it works..

Seem that the problem is somewhere else but it always crashes at fopen how is that possible?

Comment: ok, nevermind the problem is in the initialization of an int array with 10000000 elements. I still don't understand why the seg. fault always shows at the fopen (checked with gdb). Anyway thanks all for your help! Now I just need to know how to create a 10000000 positions array :)

Comment: aah well the error shows at the fopen because the array declaration was just before.. i wasn't very smart at this one haha

Comment: @GerardGarcia a VLA? That'd be too large for the stack, then.

Comment: Yes, i just saw it. I put it as a global variable and is working fine now. :)